# class.getResourceAsStream() returns null

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I've been searching for a while now and tried out some answers, but nothing worked so far..
I want to create a google-calendar-event programmatically by hitting a button.
Got the following code for my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CalManager c = new CalManager(MainActivity.this);
                try{c.addEvent();}
                catch(IOException e){
                    Log.d("mychecks", "failed");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The CalManager-class looks as follows:

```
public class CalManager {
    Context ctx;
    static String dir;
    public CalManager(Context c){
        this.ctx = c;
        dir = ctx.getFilesDir().toString();
    }
    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
            "test";

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
           dir , ".credentials/test");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
            JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
     * at ~/.credentials/calendar-java-quickstart
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY);

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = new com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in =
                CalManager.class.getResourceAsStream("clientsecret.json");
        if(in==null){
            Log.d("mychecks", "fail");
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                        .setAccessType("offline")
                        .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println(
                "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Calendar client service.
     * @return an authorized Calendar client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar
    getCalendarService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }
    public void addEvent() throws  IOException{
        com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar service =
                getCalendarService();
        Event event = new Event()
                .setSummary("TestCalendarEvent")
                .setLocation("800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103")
                .setDescription("First Test");

        DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2017-11-07T22:00:00Z");
        EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
                .setDateTime(startDateTime);
        event.setStart(start);

        DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2017-11-07T23:00:00Z");
        EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
                .setDateTime(endDateTime);
        event.setEnd(end);


        EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
                new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
        };
        Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
                .setUseDefault(false)
                .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
        event.setReminders(reminders);

        String calendarId = "bagcf5aip1o2v7ek6inb5693m8@group.calendar.google.com";
        event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
    }
}
```

My Manifest.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.user.test">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Last but not least, I've got the following gradle-file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
    core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev264-1.23.0'
}
```

At this moment, the app crashes when reaching the

```
GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
```

-statement in the CalManager's authorize()-Method, because of the

```
CalManager.class.getResourceAsStream("clientsecret.json");
```

-statement returning null. Always.

The clientsecret.json-file is located here:
[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

And are there any other further obvious issues with this code?

Thankful for any help!

**Edit:**
getResourceAsStream()-Problem solved.

Next issue is, that

```
private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
       dir , ".credentials/test");
```

throws an error: java.io.IOException: unable to create directory: /.credentials/test

Any ideas of that one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your `json` file in assets folder

[image]

and get input stream like this:

```
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("clientsecret.json");
```

Comment: Added an edit with another issue..any ideas about this one? :/ Thanks for the help!